# Got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error for ExampleInstrumentedTest

Tags: android-studio, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

Background:

I was trying to trigger a monkey test based on instrumentation.But when I ran and pushed the apk to a device, and ran the command below:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e runtime 1 -e debug false -e class com.kb.kbmonkey.ExampleInstrumentedTest com.kb.kbmonkey/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

I got the error below:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kb.kbmonkey.ExampleInstrumentedTest" on path...

So my question is:
Are java files under androidTest and test folder not exported in the apk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
./gradlew installDebugAndroidTest
```

to install instrumentation tests.

Then, your command may work.